# Value that scanf has read in not functioning as expected

Tags: c

Currently completing a programming assignment where at the beginning of the program I want the user to enter an integer as a way to select a menu item. I have made efforts to implement some degree of input checking such that the program checks if the input is 1 of the 2 menu numbers. However, even when I enter in a valid input this fails to be picked up and the program identifies it as an invalid input.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define WIDTH 15
#define HEIGHT 15
#define NAMELENGTH 128

int main() {
    //int actGrid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    //int nextGrid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    char name[NAMELENGTH];
    printf("Welcome to Conway's Game of Life. To Begin, What Is Your Name?\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
    int menSelect;
    printf("Hello %s, Please Enter the Integer Next to the Item Below That Describes How You Would Like Your Game of Life to Initially Be Set Up\n \n 1. Gosper's Glider Gun \n 2. R-Pentomino\n ", name);
    for(;;){
        int checkIn=scanf("%d",&menSelect);
        if(checkIn!=1){
            fprintf(stderr,"Scanf Has Failed to Read In Any Values\n");
        }
        if(menSelect!=1 || menSelect!=2){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s, %d Is Not a Valid Selection\nPlease Try Again\n",name,menSelect);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I honestly am quite stumped by this as the scanf function apparently reads the correct value in but then it gets dealt with as though it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is perfect except || in the 'if' condition. || returns true if at least one condition is true. When menSelect is equal to 1, it is not equal to 2 and hence, 'if' condition evaluates to true. Using && solves the problem. If menSelect equals to 1, then the 'if' condition fails and evaluates to false

```
if(menSelect!=1 && menSelect!=2){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s, %d Is Not a Valid Selection\nPlease Try Again\n",name,menSelect);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah I'm a fool! That's solved the problem perfectly. Thanks for your help.